# cannot find setter in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

Ok, so I'm calling this custom tag:

```
<%@ tag body-content="scriptless" import="java.util.*,com.serco.inquire.*,java.lang.*" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ attribute name="theID" required="true" %>
<%@ attribute name="aUser" required="true" %>
 ... do stuff with variables here...
```

With this code in the .jsp file:

```
<inq:singleRec theID="${id}" aUser="${user}" />
```

and Tomcat is telling me:

> /detailview.jsp(32,4) Unable to find setter method for attribute: aUser

(Yes, that's the line I posted above)

soooo.. what did I miss this time?

Answer (score 1):

You have camel case attribute name "aUser". It has one character "a" at the beginning and it looks like JSTL/JSP has problem with finding setter "setAUser()" in such case. Try to change "aUser" to "user" or "theUser".

Answer (score 0):

> Ok, so I'm calling this custom tag:

What you have there is not a custom tag. It is a tag file.

```
<%@ tag body-content="scriptless" import="java.util.*,com.serco.inquire.*,java.lang.*" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ attribute name="theID" required="true" %>
<%@ attribute name="aUser" required="true" %>
 ... do stuff with variables here...
```

You have used the prefix = c for your tag. Do you also have tag definitions in your web.xml ? If so, c might have already been used there for the JSTL tags. If that is the case, you might have a conflict between your tag file and the JSTL core tags.

With this code in the .jsp file:

```
<inq:singleRec theID="${id}" aUser="${user}" />
```

Where have you defined `ing` ?

Answer (score 0):

*if* you would be using a custom tag it would be because the attribute "aUser" is not present in the corresponding tag class (bean). Or, you might have changed the bean but forgot to change the TLD accordingly.